# Channel Videos import

Tags: channel, import, channel-videos

I imported content from an old CMS system into EE, 2600 entries. In one field I imported yuotube url.

Is there any way that this same URL will be automatically inserted into the chanel videos of that entry?

Comment: Just for future awareness, would be helpful to know what version of EE?  What version of Channel Videos?  You might be able to do something via datagrab (https://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab), and probably with a bit of detective work you could do the work direct in SQL.  Don't have a copy of add-on so can't be more specific - sorry!  HTH

Comment: EE 3.5.11, Channel Videos 3.2.1 . I already have the youtube url in entry text field, only that i need is to "import" ito to chanel video modul...